# NSTableView cell text not changed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview

I am using `NSTableView` in my osx application:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == self.categoryTable) {
        return [[[AppAPI shared] categoryArr] count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (nullable id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(nullable NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if (tableView == self.categoryTable) {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

        CategoryItem * cat = [[AppAPI shared] categoryArr][row];

        cellView.textField.stringValue = cat.name;

        return cellView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I use this code to insert data to the table, but all i get is rows with this text : [image]

The `cellView` is not nil

Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Where does Table View cell comes from ? IB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong delegate / data source methods

`objectValueForTableColumn:row` is supposed to return the object for the row

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    return [[AppAPI shared] categoryArr][row];
}
```

`viewForTableColumn:row:` returns the view.

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    return [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
}
```

PS: How many table views are in your design that you have to check for the right one?